# Google Sheets - Fill multiple rows with different values

Tags: html, google-sheets

I am trying to enter multiple values to another column however It seems to be harder than I thought even that or I have no idea what I am doing, Is there an easier way to add different values to a different columns?

Example:
`<span class="question" id="" onclick="expand('A101')"` - On the ID="" Element I want to add different values like this: `<span class="question" id="Q101" onclick="expand('A101')"` however the Q/A 101 will go upto 327. (So from A101 to A327 and Q101 to Q327)

I have been looking for the past day on trying to do this without it pasting everything into one cell. I have even tried doing it Visual Studio but cannot seem to find a way other than manually entering them. As you can see from the image below, I am trying to add matching values in the Question and Answer elements. Same will go for the p tags because I want to add 1 answer to each element but they will need to be different. Do I have to do this manually?

[Example Image of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elRth.png)

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of what you're trying to achieve? It's not really clear from your question as-is.

Comment: Image - https://imgur.com/sWxTcC8

As you can see from to image, I want to add the value's on the right to the id="" and ('') however they need to all be  different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xvre3UPegHlZATzYn68lw11NYRv9sfg1v6Lfzzie5NU/copy

You need to cut it into pieces - parts that are used just as plain text and variables that change.

[image]

Then you combine cells using join() function and empty delimiter "".
Id this what you were looking for?